# Better Prediction model with large DIC value

Tags: bayesian, statistical-significance, predictive-models, overfitting, information-criteria

I am using Integrated Nested Laplace Approximation (INLA) to predict birds population.In my (INLA) models, I've noticed that when I include auto spatial correlations, my predictions are good and make sense. However, when I exclude these auto spatial correlations in my second model, the predictions become poor. Additionally, I've observed that the Deviance Information Criterion (DIC) value is smaller and the residuals are better in the model without auto spatial correlations compared to the one with auto spatial correlations, which has good predictions, bigger DIC value and bad residuals. Why does this discrepancy occur? Is it because of model overfit ? I would also need some references to study such instances that happened. Thanks

Comment: It would help if you stated more clearly what "birds population" is.  Are you using predictive analytics, class prediction, some sort of regression model perhaps? What is INLA doing?  You won't get much help in this forum if you don't specify and define clearly what you are trying to predict, and a little about data format and structure. Otherwise, users can simply say: "the problem's in your data."